# Firebase Stops working when app starts second time in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, api, firebase-authentication

Here I am facing a bug in iOS Objective-C.

```
if([FIRApp defaultApp] == nil){
    [FIRApp configure];
}
```

in AppDelegate.m

If I delete App and and run a fresh install, Google Phone Auth and All REST APIs work fine. After closing the the App and starting second time. **[FIRApp configure]** If I manage not to configure app, all REST APIs start working but App starts crashing with the error: **Firebase App is not configured.**

Please reply if anyone has faced this issue and resolved.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The code, as written, should always log "Firebase App is not configured" - https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/Firebase/Core/FIRApp.m#L206

Comment: Thank @PaulBeusterien. The issue is that Firebase stops [PhoneAuthentication] and all other network requests (REST API Calls) when launching second time...